# SQL Server - Conditional IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to select from a transactions table using an IN clause determined by the value of a varchar parameter "@StatusCode". If @StatusCode is 'All Fail' then I want all records with status codes 1, 2, 3, or 5. Otherwise I want records with status code equal to the numeric value of @StatusCode. I have not found an elegant way to do this other than wrapping the entire select statement in an if condition.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE
(@StatusCode = 'All Failed' AND StatusCode IN (1,2,3,5))
OR
(IsNumeric(@StatusCode) = 1 AND StatusCode = @StatusCode)
```

this compiles but throws a conversion error when I pass 'All Failed' since the conditions aren't evaluated lazily.

So I tried with a CASE:

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE
CASE @StatusCode
WHEN 'All Failed' THEN StatusCode IN (1,2,3,5)
ELSE StatusCode = @StatusCode
END
```

but this doesn't compile and gives a syntax error at the 'IN'.

Is there a good way to do this? Or am I stuck with

```
IF @StatusCode = 'All Failed'
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE StatusCode IN (1,2,3,5)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE StatusCode = @StatusCode
END
```

Comment: what type is your `@StatusCode`?  You're attempting to use it as both a `string` and `number` - it can't be both.

Comment: sure it can.. it can also be a datetime.. a bit.. a decimal.. just needs to be converted

Comment: @StatusCode, the variable, is a string.  It's StatusCode, the field, that's numeric.

Comment: Dan Bracuk is correct

Comment: I think this is a business layer job. Based on the value of `@StatusCode` you can generate a valid sql query in more easy and elegant way by your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a COALESCE trick if your incoming variable is null to match on all items -- like this

```
  WHERE COALESCE(@nullinputvar,MatchingField) = MatchingField
```

but that does not work here because you only want to match on 4 items.  I've modified this trick to work (by first creating a local variable that is null in special case) and it might be faster than some of the other solutions where you have to a convert or cast for every row.  This of course depends on how big your table is -- at some size my solution will be faster.  A lot faster if statuscode field is an index.

```
DECLARE @numCode integer;

IF @StatusCode = 'All Fail'
BEGIN
   SET @numCode = null;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SET @numCode = CAST(@StatusCode as integer)
END

-- now the magic:

SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE COALESCE(@numCode,1) = StatusCode
   OR COALESCE(@numCode,2) = StatusCode
   OR COALESCE(@numCode,3) = StatusCode
   OR COALESCE(@numCode,5) = StatusCode
```

Comment: I like this. One question before I try it though, should those ANDs be ORs since in the case of 'All Failed' I want all of them to match?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - You could also change your input to be numeric or null and get rid of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions
WHERE
(@StatusCode = 'All Failed' AND StatusCode IN (1,2,3,5))
OR
(IsNumeric(@StatusCode) = 1 AND StatusCode =(case when @StatusCode = 'All Failed'  then StatusCode else convert(int, @StatusCode) end))
```

Comment: How is this different than the query that fails in his question?

Comment: @Hogan `AND StatusCode =convert(int, @StatusCode))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mukesh. Unfortunately this still errors with: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'All Failed' to data type int' which I think comes from the StatusCode = convert(int, @StatusCode)) part

Comment: what is passing value to this variable @StatusCode

Comment: This answer gives you the general idea of what you must do.  This is not a spoon feeding forum.

Comment: Dan, can you explain what you mean by that? I don't see anything in this answer that clears things up beyond what I've already tried

Comment: it is case when use to second condition and checking variable data to make condition

Comment: The error message is `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'All Failed' to data type int.`. It is the same as what I got before adding the convert() part

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use `If @StatusCode = 'All Failed' BEGIN` logic if this is in stored procedure.. but you if just want it in `Select` and don't care if it's sargable or not just do

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Transactions
WHERE
    (@StatusCode = 'All Failed'
     AND StatusCode IN (1,2,3,5))
    OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR,StatusCode) = @StatusCode)
```

if you're going to add logic then you dont need no magic

```
IF @StatusCode = 'All Fail'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE StatusCode IN (1, 2, 4, 5)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE StatusCode = CAST(@StatusCode AS INT)
END

-- now you dont need the magic:
```

Comment: @Hogan you mean could be?

Comment: you are converting every value of StatusCode to a string.  How could it not be slow ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions
WHERE StatusCode = (
        CASE 
            WHEN @StatusCode = 'All Failed'
                AND StatusCode = 1
                THEN 1
            WHEN @StatusCode = 'All Failed'
                AND StatusCode = 2
                THEN 2
            WHEN @StatusCode = 'All Failed'
                AND StatusCode = 3
                THEN 3
            WHEN @StatusCode = 'All Failed'
                AND StatusCode = 5
                THEN 5
            WHEN IsNumeric(@StatusCode) = 1 and @statuscode = convert(varchar(10),statuscode)
                THEN @statuscode
            END
        );
```